# Get all words from a string array as tokens using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have a String Array

```
String []str={"This is a demo","only test","nothing more"}
```

when I tokenize these array using Lucene, I am getting only
this
is
a 
demo
i am attaching my java code below:

```
try {
                for(String str2:str ){
                TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", new StringReader(str2));                               
                 CharTermAttribute termAtt = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
                    stream.reset(); 
                       while (stream.incrementToken()) {
                           System.out.println(termAtt.toString());
                              }             
                             stream.end(); 
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
```

I need each word from the array as tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got exception about `TokenStream` not being closed. This is quite trivial to fix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
    String []str={"This is a demo","only test","nothing more"};
    for (String str2 : str) {
        TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", new StringReader(str2));
        stream.reset();
        CharTermAttribute termAtt = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println(termAtt.toString());
        }
        stream.end();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Above prints

> demo
>   only
>  
>   test
>   nothing
>   more

Which is expected as the other words are stopwords.